# Physics behind inverted manometers

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics

Can someone help me understand the physics behind inverted U-Tube manometers? I’m familiar with typical manometers, and I know the approach to solve for static fluids in typical manometers.

I stumbled upon this question, and I feel that I’m missing out on something, there has to be a special way to tackle inverted tube problems.

I tried balancing the pressures on the left with that on the right and got the correct answer, but in the opposite sign. Still, I have doubts regarding the approach and I feel it is incorrect for four main reasons:

1. I used the wrong distance for the oil (it’s obviously not 0.25 m, I think it should be the red line below)
2. there’s still some water in the right tube whose pressure has not been taken into consideration (blue borders)
3. I believe there are 4 regions whose pressures contribute to the manometers reading, I labeled them below using different colors and I numbered them for your easy reference.
4. the sign is negative

Please help me remove the cloud of unclarity and obscurity I have revolving around manometric problems.

Your help is highly appreciated. Many thanks in advance.
[image]